# connecting Android App to Microcontroller ?

Tags: android, microcontroller

I`m working on home Automation project and I need to develop an Android App to control several devices. 
Is it done through GSM module to connect between the Android App & my microcontroller ? or there is another better technique ? 
how to connect Android App to GSM module ?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

with **bluetooth** you can connect an android app to external device.

Comment: thank you so much for ur answer .. but I need to connect the App to a far away device not within the bluetooth range

Comment: far away means you have to use internet

Comment: okay .. do u have any useful links to learn developing such App ?
and is it it possible to establish this conection via GSM & how ?

Comment: sorry, i tried with bluetooth only for same requirement. I never tried with others and no information with me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to implement REST approach with 2 phones?

From the first phone try to update some variable in a server.

From the second phone keep fetching the value from the server. Your second phone needs to be connected with microcontroller using bluetooth / serial port.

That would be straight forward.